# When will I encounter issues with the type Double in C# with 8 decimal places for Bitcoin?

Tags: c#, floating-point, double, floating-accuracy, bitcoin

I remember reading issues about certain math operations and the type `double`, but I forget when they would occur, or how I need to deal with them.

A "Bitcoin" is a float that has 8 decimal places.  I'm assuming that I use they type `double` with it, and not any other kind (decimal, etc).  Is this correct?

What other issues should I consider as I write, debug, and test an application that uses 8 decimal points?

Comment: If you want 8 accurate decimal places I recommend not using a float.

Comment: Ahh... right a Double is needed.

Comment: Well I was off on that one too... should be decimal.  Thank goodness I came to check!

Comment: [According to my googling:](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=c58340qe6n09pelu56o93lj6q4&topic=13837.msg189952#msg189952)

_Internally, everything [in bitcoin processing code] is represented using 64-bit integers. It's only some of the interfacing code that uses floating point for convenience_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are doing anything with money you should be using [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You will be getting accuracy issues well before 8 decimal places, depending on the size of the number.

As there is a fixed amount of space (number of significant figures) `float` can represent numbers in the range -1 to +1 more accurately than it can numbers in the range 9,000 to 10,000 (say).

[Float only has 7 digits of precision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b1e65aza%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) this means that it can't represent numbers down to 8 decimal places.

[Double has 15-16 digits of precision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/678hzkk9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) so is more accurate but still not accurate enough for monetary calculations - particularly with large values.

If they call it a `float` then it's misleading. They probably mean "floating point type" which `float` is only one.

Answer (score 3):

If you are worried about decimal places and accuracy, in particular when dealing with currencies, you should be using [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx) not `float` or `double`.